# Cannot run 'make' in VScode Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, makefile

For a school assignment, I am trying to compile a C file using a provided Makefile in Vscode. The makefile contains the following:

```
CFLAGS += -std=gnu11 -g
EXES    = greet

all:  $(EXES)
clean:
    rm -f $(EXES)

greet: greet.c
# don't treat all and clean as file targets
.PHONY: all clean
```

When I run make in the VScode terminal, it gives me:
bash: make: command not found

Why is this happening? The assignment says this:

> The accompanying Makefile will build the program greet. Thus, you can compile the
> program by running make. The make program will print out each command that it uses to
> compile the program. Note that if you run make twice in a row, the second time it won’t do
> anything, because it knows your source file hasn’t changed.
> Run the program using the following command:
> ./greet

I don't know if this has anything to do with my tasks.json file in VScode?
I also ran across this VSCode extension: https://naereen.github.io/Makefiles-support-for-VSCode/
It says Vscode now has something built-in: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/master/extensions/make
I don't know how to install this.

Comment: make is not a standard program on Windows.  You'll have to install it separately.  That's why you're getting "command not found": it's not installed.  Note that adding Visual Code extensions to _support_ make is not the same thing as installing make.

Comment: how do i install make? is there a non-third party extension to support make?

Comment: You don't install it through Visual Code, that's what I'm trying to say.  It's not an extension to Visual Code, it's a completely different program.  Visual Code "extensions" only provide _interfaces_ to make.  How you install it depends on what operating system you're using.  If you're on a GNU/Linux system and it's not installed, use your package manager to install it.  If you're on Windows, I can't really help because I don't use Windows, but try googling for something like "gnu make windows" and see what you find.